# Can't add two mySQL duration values in php

Tags: php, date, time

The $res['FitnessActivityTime'] contains 2 entries, the first is 04:09:00 and the second is 01:04:00 . These are retrieved by an mySQL table.

```
foreach ($res as $row) {

    $distance += $row['FitnessDistance'];
    $time += strtotime($row['FitnessActivityTime']);
}
echo "Distance is " . $distance . " and time is " . date("H:i:s",$time) . "<br>";
```

My problem is that the result that returns is :

> Distance is 5 and time is 11:13:00

While I need it to return

> Distance is 5 and time is 05:13:00

To clarify what I need is hours second minutes of counting, not a time in the day(ex. 01:04:00 AM)

Comment: What is the result of `var_dump($row['FitnessActivityTime']);`?

Comment: explode your $res['FitnessActivityTime']  values and add them as you want.

Comment: @Loko i put the var_dump inside the loop and got this string(8) "04:09:00" string(8) "01:04:00" Distance is 5 and time is 11:13:00

Comment: Do you have an activity start and end times?

Comment: `date`/`strtotime` deals with *dates*, not durations. The PHP class modelling durations is [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php).

Comment: @NigelRen no it is only duration.

Comment: @deceze can you post a solution?

Comment: It's converting your times to date + time and then adding them. Take a look at the output from [here](http://strtotime.co.uk/?str=01%3A04%3A00)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guessing your array $row['FitnessActivityTime'] is like

```
$row['FitnessActivityTime'][] = '04:09:00';
$row['FitnessActivityTime'][] = '01:04:00';
```

Now explode your string

```
$parts = explode(':', $row['FitnessActivityTime']);
$seconds+= ($parts[0] * 60 * 60) + ($parts[1] * 60) + $parts[2];
```

And finally

```
echo  gmdate("H:i:s", $seconds);
```